# How to access html button values in django views

Tags: python, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap, django-views

I am working on a django web application. The application has a few buttons inside a form. These buttons act like toggle switches. When a user submits the form, I want to access the values of the button in the django `views`. Take a look at the image below for better understanding.

[image]

I designed the form with Bootstrap. this is the code to the HTML form.

```
<form>
    {% csrf_token %}

    ...

    <p class='details-scrape'>Select the items you want to add to the list</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
        Tomato
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
        Eggs
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
        Bread
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
        Beans
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
        Cheese
    </button>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg mt-5">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my views.py code

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # ------------- New code will come here -----------------
        #access the values of the clicked buttons here...

        return redirect(index)

    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML forms, only the input data is transmitted to server.
but in this case you can do this:

1. Add hidden inputs for each toggle button.
2. In form's 'onsubmit' event call a javascript function.
3. In the function get the values of buttons.
4. Insert values to hidden inputs (for example set the value of hidden input with id 'input1' with value of button with id 'btn1')
5. Submit the form.
6. Now you can access hidden inputs values that contain buttons values.

Comment: Hello. I have added the `hidden inputs` and the jquery code to populate the field value on button click. But I am not able to access the value of the inputs through my views with this code `request.POST.get('tomato-input')`. This just returns `None`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you dont send a key-data to server django will raise an error:key not found.
i think your are sending inputs to server but you cant set value to hidden inputs with jquery.
if problem not solved show your js code and html form